# B30 door bell camera it says that I can't get the app for my phone because it is only available for an older version phone

Tags: camera, android-app

I have a B30 doorbell camera and I have a Motorola G Pure phone and the app it says to download isn't available for my phone only for an older version and I can't find an app to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome Frank! Do you have a link to the manufacturer of your doorbell camera, and perhaps a link to the spec sheet?  If so, please add them to your question. Those may help yield a quality answer.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have been gifted a B30 doorbell and also have this issue. It uses 'anyhome' app which is not available for newer android versions, is there any alternative?
Link to doorbell: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wireless-Doorbell-Security-Control-Intercom/dp/B07X976S1P
App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.ubia.anyhome

Sorry but I can't identify a known brand of doorbell.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/68035)